# Viewing realtime IRC logs?

Tags: xampp, irc

I'm running an IRC bot for a channel I help manage, it logs everything to a .txt file, which is located in a directory on my webserver. As it is, you can view the the file by going to server.com/irc/logs/11-14-2013.txt. That's all well and good, but if you want to see what's going on, you have to keep refreshing the page.

I'd like to make it easier for users to view these logs without actually logging onto the channel. I was thinking of something that could display and refresh the logs without any user input? Does such a thing exist, or am I going to have to code something up myself? Or are there any other solutions that would work?

tl;dr, need a way of users viewing IRC logs in realtime or near realtime, without logging into channel.

Comment: What do you have in mind? A ajaxy web page or something similar?